# Intuition on exp function

Tags: calculus, exponential-function, intuition

So in my calc1 class we introduced $e$ and $\exp(x)$ by searching for a function with the property that it is equal to its derivative. We get the well known infinite sum, all good.
With the Cauchy product and the Binomial theorem we proof that $\exp(x+y)=\exp(x)\exp(y)$ is correct.
What I don't understand is why the function that is equal to its derivative coincidentally satisfies $\exp(x+y)=\exp(x)\exp(y)$ and I'm looking for a non-formal explanation. Thanks in advance, and I apologize if I didn't find any obvious resources on that question on the internet.

Comment: That's because $\exp(x+y)$ as a function of $x$ is also equal to its derivative, it just has another value at $x=0$. So there's no "coincidence".

Comment: Define $\exp(x)$ canonically as $e^x$. Then $e^{x+y}=e^xe^y$ follows from postulates of real number operations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fix $y\in\Bbb R$ and consider the functions $f,g\colon\Bbb R\longrightarrow\Bbb R$ defined by$$f(x)=\exp(x+y)\quad\text{and}\quad g(x)=\exp(x)\exp(y).$$Then $f'=f$ and $g'=g$. So$$\left(\frac fg\right)'=\frac{gf'-fg'}{g^2}=0.$$Therefore, $\frac fg$ is constant. But $f(0)=g(0)\bigl(=\exp(y)\bigr)$, and so $f=g$.

Answer (score 1):

By the additive property, if you shift the argument, you get a function proportional to the original:

$$f(x+1)=f(x)f(1).$$

Hence the slope of the chord is also proportional:

$$\frac{\Delta f}{\Delta x}=f(x+1)-f(x)=(f(1)-1)f(x)=cf(x).$$

*The same goes for the slope of a tangent.*

---

If we consider $f(\lambda x)$ instead of $f(x)$, which is a stretched version of $f$, the slopes are modified accordingly, and it will be possible to find a $\lambda$ such that $c=1$.

---

On this plot, the function $3^x$ (blue), the slope of chords for unit intervals (green) and the slope of tangents (magenta). All proportional.

[image]